# Is there a Germanic word for "science"?

Tags: single-word-requests

German and Dutch have their own distinct word for "science". Whereas, in English, "science" is borrowed from Latin/French, with all Romance languages having a word that is similar to it (I.e ciencia).

Comment: Why do you think there would be, or should be, such a word in English? According to some studies, the majority of English words comes from French/Latin/Greek - see for instance [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_language_influences_in_English). Using a Romance word is arguably a very English thing to do.

Comment: Knowledge or wisdom

Comment: I would say the Dutch and German word translates roughly in English to "knowing craft" or "knowing - ship". Science is translated from Latin which means knowledge. So the two actually has the same meaning. Your argument is like saying why is the word for knowledge not the same in English and Dutch/German. The answer it's a generic word which are usually unique.

Comment: Wissenschaften                     ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I know very little German but I do know that the language has chosen to avoid those technical words derived from Latin and Greek which most other European languages use, e.g. it uses 'Fernsprecher'  (far-speaker) for 'telephone'. English does use such words, so the question isn't relevant to English.

Answer (score 5):

In English? Not really. So Poul Anderson came up with *worldken* for science in his famous “Uncleftish Beholding” (yclept “Atomic Theory”), and *worldken folk* for his scientists.

Here’s just the start of it:

> For most of its being, mankind did not know what things are made
>   of, but could only guess. With the growth of **worldken**, we began
>   to learn, and today we have a beholding of stuff and work that
>   watching bears out, both in the workstead and in daily life.
>
> The underlying kinds of stuff are the *firststuffs*, which link
>   together in sundry ways to give rise to the rest. Formerly we
>   knew of ninety-two firststuffs, from waterstuff, the lightest and
>   barest, to ymirstuff, the heaviest. Now we have made more, such
>   as aegirstuff and helstuff.
>
> The firststuffs have their being as motes called *unclefts*.
>   These are mightly small; one seedweight of waterstuff holds a
>   tale of them like unto two followed by twenty-two naughts. Most
>   unclefts link together to make what are called *bulkbits*. Thus,
>   the waterstuff bulkbit bestands of two waterstuff unclefts, the
>   sourstuff bulkbit of two sourstuff unclefts, and so on. (Some
>   kinds, such as sunstuff, keep alone; others, such as iron, cling
>   together in ices when in the fast standing; and there are yet
>   more yokeways.) When unlike clefts link in a bulkbit, they make
>   *bindings*. Thus, water is a binding of two waterstuff unclefts
>   with one sourstuff uncleft, while a bulkbit of one of the
>   forestuffs making up flesh may have a thousand thousand or more
>   unclefts of these two firststuffs together with coalstuff and
>   chokestuff.
>
> At first is was thought that the uncleft was a hard thing that
>   could be split no further; hence the name. Now we know it is made
>   up of lesser motes. There is a heavy *kernel* with a forward
>   bernstonish lading, and around it one or more light motes with
>   backward ladings. The least uncleft is that of ordinary
>   waterstuff. Its kernel is a lone forwardladen mote called a
>   *firstbit*. Outside it is a backwardladen mote called a
>   *bernstonebit*. The firstbit has a heaviness about 1840-fold that
>   of the bernstonebit. Early **worldken** **folk** thought bernstonebits
>   swing around the kernel like the earth around the sun, but now we
>   understand they are more like waves or clouds.

There’s more where that came from, like this:

> By shooting motes into kernels, **worldken folk** have shifted
>   samesteads of one firststuff into samesteads of another. Thus did
>   they make ymirstuff into aegirstuff and helstuff, and they have
>   afterward gone beyond these. The heavier firststuffs are all
>   highly lightrottish and therefore are not found in the
>   greenworld.

It’s quite creative and all, but what we speak now is perfectly fine.

Comment: I *totally* forgot about “Uncleftish Beholding”! Thank you so much for reminding me of it! I think that’s where I first encountered *yclept*, and kept it as a bit of a souvenir.